# The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings does not point to a JDK

Tags: java, settings

Everytime I open visual studio it gives me this error

The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings (C:\Program Files\Java) does not point to a JDK.

I have tried changing it to the specific jdk folder through visual studio's settings, the program files 86 and changing the java home variable in my environment variable settings on my computer. Currently I have it set too :   "java.home": "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2"
Any thoughts?